# How to preview a pdf file in Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, pdf, laravel-8

How can I preview a PDF file in Laravel 8? I want it so that when a user clicks on the link, it will open a new tab and display a PDF from DB.

**Controller**

```
public function noticeView($id)
{
    $notice = Notice::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();
    $pathToFile = ($notice->file);

    return response()->stream($pathToFile);
}
```

Route

```
Route::get('/notice-view/{id}', [FrontendController::class, 'noticeView']);
```

Comment: Change stream to file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your controller like this :

```
public function noticeView($id)
{
   $notice = Notice::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();
   $pathToFile = $notice->file;
   $fileName =  $notice->fileName;
   $path = $pathToFile.'/';
   $file = public_path($path.$fileName);
   return response()->file($file);
}
```

Then add attribute `"target=_blank"` in your HTML

Comment: Could you include some explanation of your answer?